# How to know the classes supported by which version of Delphi?

Tags: delphi

From time to time, when I see a specific class, such as `TTask`, it is surely supported by the latest version of Delphi, eg:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Threading.TTask

However, how can I know which Delphi version started to support it? Before Delphi supported it, is there another class that can be used as a replacement for it?

Where can I find such information?

Comment: Generally speaking, such documentation is not available anywhere.  You will just have to pay attention to the "What's New" docs in each new release to see what was added. Unfortunately, most of the older version docs are no longer online.  For the record, `TTask` (and the PPL in general) was introduced in Delphi XE7, IIRC. There were no similar classes in previous versions, you had to write such logic yourself using `TThread` or similar.

Comment: It used to be possible to manually change part of the URL for documentation that is specifying Delphi version. For instance from `Alexandria` to `XE2`. This would open old documentation for `XE2` on that specific topic if it already existed then. But I see that it is now automatically redirecting to the newest version of documentation if you try to chose anything older than Delphi 10.0 Seattle.

Comment: Some online help pages give an indication of when the class/method/property/etc. was added (or documented?).  For example, the help page for the FMX TLayout has near the bottom of the page "Categories: API Documentation | XE2"

Comment: @SilverWarior  You're right about redirecting.  Even if you use the navigation bar on the left, select the "Older Versions" option, then select from the list of versions back to 2010, it will take you to the Alexandria page!